# Use SQL Query in VB.net to retireve adjacant row data

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, insert

I am currently coding in VB.net using windows form applications and an sql server for my tables. I am creating an order form with two comboboxes, one for the type of material to be ordered and one for a name. There is also a submit button at the bottom to run the SQL "Insert Into" code. The material combobox is filled with a column of material types from an SQL table called "tbl.channel". Each material type under that column has a part number, ID, and bundle size associated with that row. I want ALL of the information associated with that material type to write into a new table that records all the orders, with the user only selecting the material type from a combobox. How can I use a "Select From" sql code to pull the associated information with that material type to be written into a new table that tracks all the material ordered?

```
Try
            Dim connectionstring As String = Nothing
            Dim connection As SqlConnection
            Dim command As SqlCommand
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim ds As New DataTable
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Dim sql As String = Nothing

        connectionstring = "DATA SOURCE = BNSigma\Core ; integrated security = true"
        sql = "Select Channel, [Bundle Size], ID from Production.dbo.tblchannel"

        connection = New SqlConnection(connstring)

        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try



    Try
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Production.dbo.tbl (Channel, OrderedBy, Date1, BundleSize, ID) Values (@Channel, @Orderedby, @getdate(), @BundleSize, @ID)", conn1)
                With comm1.Parameters
                    .AddWithValue("@Channel", CBChannel.SelectedValue)
                    .AddWithValue("@OrderedBy", CBName.SelectedValue)
                    .AddWithValue("@BundleSize", CBChannel.SelectedValue)
                    .AddWithValue("@ID", CBChannel.SelectedValue)
                End With
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to make SQL connection")
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: Sorry guys, something went wrong with the top bit of my code, that is a try statement followed by dim of my variables.

Comment: Do you really need to post such huge code to explain your problem?

Comment: Just trying to give you all the data i can Rahul.

Comment: I don't think that's too much code.

Comment: I still don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your goal, but are you looking to just do this?

```
INSERT Production.dbo.tbl (Channel, OrderedBy, Date1, BundleSize, ID) 
SELECT Channel, @Orderedby, getdate(), BundleSize, ID
FROM tbl.channel 
WHERE ID = @ID
```

I am pretty well convinced though that you should only be writing the channel.ID to the orders table -- do you have a compelling reason to write the extra values?

Comment: I think this code will work modified, the only problem is that the channel ordered table, or the table that is tracking the orders was not set up to track the ID from the channel table. The previous coder did not set this up well at all. Could I change the where ID=@ID too macth the material type column?

Comment: in short terms the id on the ordered channel table is just a long ass list from 1 to however many entries are in that table.

Comment: I'm not really following.  If you want to include the schemas for the two (or more) tables in question, we can look at them.  Are you in a position to repair the database or are you required to limp along with it broken?

Comment: Considering there are thousands of tracked entries i think it would be better to just reset up a new table.  I would have to talk to the other engineers first though to see if the signal would affect the materials department.

Answer (score 0):

SQL lets you use a SELECT query to populate the values for an INSERT statement. Something like this:

```vb
Public Sub PopulateOrder(ByVal MaterialID As Integer, ByVal SalesName As String)

    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Production.dbo.tbl (Channel, OrderedBy, Date1, BundleSize, ID) SELECT Channel, @SalesName, current_timestamp, [Bundle Size], ID from Production.dbo.tblchannel WHERE ID = @MaterialID"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        'Better to declare a specific database type than let .AddWithValue() try to infer one for you
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SalesName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = SalesName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MaterialID", SqlDbtype.Int).Value = MaterialID

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Call it like with code similar to this:

```
PopulateOrder(CBChannel.SelectedValue, CBName.SelectedValue)
```

But for what it's worth, it's almost always a bad idea to duplicate this information across tables.

Comment: When you say declare a specific database, could i declare a table withing the database?

Comment: I said "`declare a specific database **type**`". Look how I used a type name as part of creating the parameter. The `AddWithValue()` method will infer that type name for you, but it has problems where sometimes it gets the type name wrong.

Comment: But to answer the question: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can use `CREATE TABLE` and  `USE DATABASE` commands as part of SQL strings from VB.